# HTML templates in NetBeans

Tags: php, html, netbeans, layout, templates

Is it possible to do template layouts which you can assign to all your pages within NetBeans. (The equivalent to Dreamweaver templates)

Please note this is a PHP Project

Thanks in advance!

Any takers on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm pretty sure that this isnt possible in netbeans, I would imagine though that this isnt really necessary if you are using a proper MVC approach or a fully abstracted template class like Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

In your *Files* window (CTRL + 2) select the file you want as a template. Right click it and select *'Save As Template'* then stick it in the PHP folder.

Comment: Thanks this creates a template great. But I was wondering if there was a way that if I updated/edited that template all files created with that template would get updated also? Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure to be hounest. I havnt used it for a while. I'd say no- but theres no harm in giving it a try :)